# How to implement saveEventually in CloudKit

Tags: parse-platform, cloudkit

One of true greatest Parse features is PFObject's saveEventually method. From Parse’s doc:

**saveEventually**
***Saves this object to the server at some unspecified time in the future, even if Parse is currently inaccessible.***

Basically it saves it locally and keeps trying to push Parse whenever it feels there is a connection. 
How can someone implement the same functionality using CloudKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CloudKit you have to do everything yourself.

You could set the object in a [queue](http://waynewbishop.com/swift/stacks-queues/) (in memory and persist to file in case of an app restart) When the object is saved to CloudKit, you can remove it from the queue.

You could create a special queue object that would contain the actual data plus some extra information like timestamps and retry count.

In your AppDelegate application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions you should read the queue from file and continue processing